# Сортировка многомерного массива SORT_NUMERIC

Tags: php

Есть многомерный массив с где сортирую по возрастанию по строке типа

```
[19] => Array
    (
        [name] => Тест 15
        [size] => 60x120
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [name] => Тест 14
        [size] => 63x125
    )
```

Проблема в том что 60x120 должен быть по сути первым, а не 19 по счету. Первый же содержит 110x190

Сам код сортировки

```
    usort($text, function($a, $b) {

    return $a['size'] <=> $b['size'];

});
```

Для обычного массива прекрасно работал с `sort($txt, SORT_NUMERIC);`

Comment: то есть весь вопрос в том чтобы приводить сравниваемые значения к числовому виду вручную?

Comment: @Ипатьев Вопрос так сказать в том как SORT_NUMERIC применить к многомерному массиву

Comment: НУ ТО ЕСТЬ весь вопрос в том чтобы приводить сравниваемые значения к числовому виду вручную?

Comment: Какой метод сортировки массива, по сравнению его строковых значений, или цифр, содержащихся в этих строках? Как вам уже написали, уточните свой вопрос с примером логики сортировки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_multisort( array_column($text, "size"), SORT_NATURAL, $text );
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]